# Scalable self-hosted file upload to Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, upload, nonblocking

We have a Rails 3 Application (running on Passenger) that sits behind a NGINX Server (load balancer). A major feature is file uploading from the browser. What technology is a good choice for handling the file uploads? The goal would be not to affect the application servers and be scalable over more than one server if needed. The Node.js Implementation [node-formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable) looks nice. But I would prefer a Ruby Implementation to keep the toolstack uniform.

The files are expected be somewhere between 100 KB and 100 MB.

The current ideas would be to use [Thin](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/) or [Goliath](https://github.com/postrank-labs/goliath). But I am unsure if "non-blocking" is really the main key here. Is there maybe a S3 like OSS software that can be deployed on our own servers?

Comment: There are a few reimplementations of the S3 api, including eucalyptus and riak-cs

Comment: @FrederickCheung Thanks for mentioning riak-cs. It looks promising. We will have a closer look into it. Eucalyptus is from what I know the whole big IaaS + Storage Cloud Platform. That would be too much. But I'll check that, too.

Comment: its hard to tell if you are asking how a client would upload files or how to store files at large scale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenStack storage is a great alternative

http://www.openstack.org/software/openstack-storage/

and if i remember correctly this is what Rackspace runs cloudfiles on so it would probably be compatible with the Carrierwave-fog from the ruby side using the rackspace driver. Just checked it actually supports the S3 api so any S3 adapters/gems will work fine.